# JSF 2.2 displayValueOnly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a possibility to use the option "displayValueOnly" (https://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/DisplayValueOnly) with JSF 2.2?

I think the link above is explaining the feature of Tomahawk which exists only for older JSF versions, right?

Is there a alternative for creating a read and edit mode without creating two elements and without using "readOnly" or "disabled"?

Thank you!

Comment: Why without readonly or disabled AND not creating two elements? So you want a complex solution?

Comment: I would like to have a simple solution like displayValueOnly ;-) Maybe with defining an own inputText if necessary...
readonly or disabled is no solution because of e.g. a overfull input field which would 'cut' the content...

Comment: DisplayValueOnly is not simple. It requires a whole set of components that support it. And is it **only** for inpuText? The creating a taglib with two components in it AND use omnifaces massAttribute http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute hels

Answer (score 0):

Tomahawk is not compatible with JSF 2.2 - I've tried a few components and they work fine for others you've to work on the Tomahawk source.